# PIVOT Perfomance is very slow in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have attached one sample.This is like query method.But i am using this query in stored procedure .Query is very fast.But in procedure very slow.What is the reason.

```
DECLARE @lsId VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @lsDate VARCHAR(20);
SET @lsId = '802306';
SET @lsDate = '2017-10-02';
SELECT fld_region [REGION],
       ISNULL([CINEMA], 0) [CINEMA],
       ISNULL([ECONOMY], 0) [ECONOMY],
       ISNULL([HD PRIME], 0) [HD PRIME],
       ISNULL([HD SUPREME], 0) [HD SUPREME],
       ISNULL([HD ULTRA], 0) [HD ULTRA],
       ISNULL([INDI], 0) [INDI],
       ISNULL([KUSHI], 0) [KUSHI],
       ISNULL([MEGA], 0) [MEGA],
       ISNULL([ROI VALUE], 0) [ROI VALUE],
       ISNULL([ROI VALUE PLUS], 0) [ROI VALUE PLUS],
       ISNULL([SOUTH VALUE], 0) [SOUTH VALUE],
       ISNULL([SUPER VALUE], 0) [SUPER VALUE],
       ISNULL([WORLD], 0) [WORLD]
FROM
(
    SELECT b.fld_region,
           a.fld_pack_name,
           a.fld_count
    FROM TBL_ACTIVE_CUSTOMER_DT_PLAN_WISE a
         JOIN VHierarchyDT b ON b.FLD_DTCODE = a.FLD_DTCODE
                                AND b.SH_ID = @lsId
                                AND a.fld_act_date = @lsDate
) x PIVOT(SUM(fld_count) FOR fld_pack_name IN([CINEMA],
                                              [ECONOMY],
                                              [HD PRIME],
                                              [HD SUPREME],
                                              [HD ULTRA],
                                              [INDI],
                                              [KUSHI],
                                              [MEGA],
                                              [ROI VALUE],
                                              [ROI VALUE PLUS],
                                              [SOUTH VALUE],
                                              [SUPER VALUE],
                                              [WORLD])) p;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific. (sql-server perhaps.)

Comment: Looks like SQL Server but please tag. Slow SP execution might be a parameter sniffing issue

Comment: `JOIN VHierarchyDT` suggest the use of a view; what is the performance of the inner query like?

Comment: Also, if it is running slower when called as part of a stored procedure, it would be nice to see the estimated and actual query execution plan of the procedure. Initially you could try to alter the procedure and put an `option(recompile)` to this query and check the execution time.

Comment: Also i am using option(recompile) and OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@lsProcUserId UNKNOWN,@lsProcDate UNKNOWN)) in stored procedure.But still very slow .

Comment: Mh, not enough information to be able to help you here. We do not know if you have indexes on the columns you are joining, but you mention that it runs fast as a single query and slower as part of a procedure. We do not know if this is a possible sniffing issue or not..having only this piece of code provided here it is a bit difficult to really provide some help. Good luck!

Comment: Try the [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) `OPTION(HASH GROUP)`, see if that helps.

Comment: Or rather, just `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`, in that case do not use the option to recompile.

Comment: OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN) also tried.But still very slow

Comment: Maybe try the old-school way of bypassing parameter sniffing: create local variables for each parameter in the stored procedure, then assign each parameter value to a local variable, and in the rest of the procedure only use the local variables.

Comment: @TT. trying things in random isn't going to help. It can hurt, a lot though. The OP hasn't posted nearly enough information. What about *transactions*? What is that stored procedure doing and who is calling it? Where is the execution plan? What does the Activity Monitor show?

Comment: @Raj what are the table schemas? Indexes? Execution plan? How many rows?  What does that stored procedure do? Are there any transactions? What is the *server's* version? 2017? Or 2008 R2? A LOT has changed in the last 10 years. You don't provide enough information to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @Raj the performance of the query in SSMS doesn't mean much if the data sizes differ. Or if one query is against your production server and another against a development database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the variable datatypes

```
DECLARE @lsId INT; --If this is the correct data type
DECLARE @lsDate DATE; --If this is the correct data type

SET @lsId = 802306;
SET @lsDate = '2017-10-02';

SELECT fld_region [REGION],
       ISNULL([CINEMA], 0) [CINEMA],
       ISNULL([ECONOMY], 0) [ECONOMY],
       ISNULL([HD PRIME], 0) [HD PRIME],
       ISNULL([HD SUPREME], 0) [HD SUPREME],
       ISNULL([HD ULTRA], 0) [HD ULTRA],
       ISNULL([INDI], 0) [INDI],
       ISNULL([KUSHI], 0) [KUSHI],
       ISNULL([MEGA], 0) [MEGA],
       ISNULL([ROI VALUE], 0) [ROI VALUE],
       ISNULL([ROI VALUE PLUS], 0) [ROI VALUE PLUS],
       ISNULL([SOUTH VALUE], 0) [SOUTH VALUE],
       ISNULL([SUPER VALUE], 0) [SUPER VALUE],
       ISNULL([WORLD], 0) [WORLD]
FROM
(
    SELECT b.fld_region,
           a.fld_pack_name,
           a.fld_count
    FROM TBL_ACTIVE_CUSTOMER_DT_PLAN_WISE a
         JOIN VHierarchyDT b ON b.FLD_DTCODE = a.FLD_DTCODE
                                AND b.SH_ID = @lsId
                                AND a.fld_act_date = @lsDate
) x PIVOT(SUM(fld_count) FOR fld_pack_name IN([CINEMA],
                                              [ECONOMY],
                                              [HD PRIME],
                                              [HD SUPREME],
                                              [HD ULTRA],
                                              [INDI],
                                              [KUSHI],
                                              [MEGA],
                                              [ROI VALUE],
                                              [ROI VALUE PLUS],
                                              [SOUTH VALUE],
                                              [SUPER VALUE],
                                              [WORLD])) p;
```

OR Pulling initial data into a temporary table

```
 DECLARE @lsId INT; --If this is the correct data type
 DECLARE @lsDate DATE; --If this is the correct data type

    SET @lsId = 802306;
    SET @lsDate = '2017-10-02';


    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##PivotData') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE ##PivotData

    SELECT b.fld_region,
           a.fld_pack_name,
           a.fld_count
    INTO ##PivotData --I would normally create and not select into.
    FROM TBL_ACTIVE_CUSTOMER_DT_PLAN_WISE a
    JOIN VHierarchyDT b ON b.FLD_DTCODE = a.FLD_DTCODE
                        AND b.SH_ID = @lsId
                        AND a.fld_act_date = @lsDate

    SELECT fld_region [REGION],
           ISNULL([CINEMA], 0) [CINEMA],
           ISNULL([ECONOMY], 0) [ECONOMY],
           ISNULL([HD PRIME], 0) [HD PRIME],
           ISNULL([HD SUPREME], 0) [HD SUPREME],
           ISNULL([HD ULTRA], 0) [HD ULTRA],
           ISNULL([INDI], 0) [INDI],
           ISNULL([KUSHI], 0) [KUSHI],
           ISNULL([MEGA], 0) [MEGA],
           ISNULL([ROI VALUE], 0) [ROI VALUE],
           ISNULL([ROI VALUE PLUS], 0) [ROI VALUE PLUS],
           ISNULL([SOUTH VALUE], 0) [SOUTH VALUE],
           ISNULL([SUPER VALUE], 0) [SUPER VALUE],
           ISNULL([WORLD], 0) [WORLD]
    FROM ##PivotData x 
    PIVOT(SUM(fld_count) FOR fld_pack_name IN([CINEMA],
                                              [ECONOMY],
                                              [HD PRIME],
                                              [HD SUPREME],
                                              [HD ULTRA],
                                              [INDI],
                                              [KUSHI],
                                              [MEGA],
                                              [ROI VALUE],
                                              [ROI VALUE PLUS],
                                              [SOUTH VALUE],
                                              [SUPER VALUE],
                                              [WORLD])) p;
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. There is a reason people can't post comments with rep less than 50. You have to get acquainted with SO first, understand that an *answer* is supposed to be that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos; I do apologise, that the inability to post a comment lead me to the only other option I had which was to post as an answer.  I am more than aware a comment is a comment and an answer is not a comment.  Just trying to help the OP.   Thanks for your useful advice.